# Acesso a aplicação local via celular

Tags: aplicação-web, dns, domínio

Tenho uma aplicação web rodando em um computador em minha rede local. Essa aplicação é acessada por celulares conectados a minha rede via wi-fi usando o endereço IP da máquina servidora da aplicação. Para facilitar o acesso configurei um computador como servidor DNS com um domínio direcionando para esse computador, para que o pessoal pudesse acessar com um nome como `aplicacao.com.br/app`. Tudo funciona perfeitamente.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer esse serviço de DNS via roteador? Implementei o servidor DNS para teste, mas se eu puder evitar esse custo seria ótimo, além de tirar uma peça do quebra cabeças que pode eventualmente trazer problemas caso para de funcionar por algum motivo. Quanto menos intermediários melhor.

Comment: ja pesquisei por isso uma vez e nao obtive resultado, parece que o roteador não é capaz disso. vou ficar aqui na expectativa tambem

Comment: no-ip não serve?

Comment: Pelo que entendi o no-ip é para acesso externo e preciso que todo acesso seja pela rede interna. A empresa quer usar o seu próprio nome de domínio também...